# Best method for running parallel PHP scripts

Tags: php, parallel-processing, pthreads, pcntl

I'd like to run 3 *different* simple scripts at once that each scrapes websites content and returns a string. Which of the pcntl, pthreads, background exec() methods is most suitable? I'm mostly interested in low resource consumption.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer generally.

Which resource you want to optimise?

Anyway the first example here answers your question mostly: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; ++$i) {
        $pid = pcntl_fork();

        if (!$pid) {
            sleep(1);
            print "In child $i\n";
            exit($i);
        }
    }

    while (pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) {
        $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
        echo "Child $status completed\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I mean RAM allocated by the resousrce. If I understand it well, pcntl_fork is used for running the same process/ script in multiple instances, right? I better add the word "different" into my Q.

Answer (score 0):

Because I found my host doesn't provide the extensions, the exec way is the only one to go. However pthreads seems to be the most efficient one.